# try-except on pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, styling, try-except

Try except block returns nothing. How can I fix this? If I fix it, how can I make the change permanent ?

```
def color(val):
    """Takes a scalar and returns a string with the css 
    property 'bg-color:red' for negative string, black otherwise"""
    color="blue" if val%2==1 else "yellow"
    return f"background-color: {color}"

df = sns.load_dataset("flights")



try:
    df.style.applymap(color)
except:
    Exception
```

Comment: What is the expected result here? Try-except block never returns anything by itself: it's exception handling. And in your exception handling, you are essentially doing nothing. "Exception" is not practically an operation or statement of any sort. It's just a built-in exception type.

Comment: I wanna make the background-color of odd numbers blue, of even numbers yellow in passengers and year columns and I wanna make the change permanent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try:

create 2 seperate functions:

```
def color_negative(val):
    cond=(val<0)
    return ['color: red' if v else 'color: black' for v in cond]

def color_positive(val):
    cond=(val%2==0)
    return ['background-color: blue' if v else 'background-color: yellow' for v in cond]
```

Finally:

```
out=df.style.apply(color_negative,subset=['passengers']).apply(color_positive,subset=['passengers'])
```

Now if you print `out` you will get your expected output